# how to read values from a structure in C

Tags: c, embedded, hardware, embedding

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define msize 4096

struct memory
{
    int a[msize];
};

void main()
{
    struct memory m;
    m.a[0]=250; // temperature value of 25,0
    m.a[4]=01; // heater status OFF
    m.a[8]=240; // temperature value of 24,0
    m.a[12]=00; // heater status ON
    m.a[16]=220; // temperature value of 22,0
    m.a[20]=00; // heater status ON
    read(&m);

}

void read(struct memory m)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(msize);i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", m.a[i]);
    }
}
```

My code creates a structure of size 4096 bytes, an object for the structure and then assigns values to i.

On compilation, the compiler throws a "first defined here" error in the `read` function.

Also, can someone please help me to convert this read value to ASCII?

Comment: When there's an error you should show it in the question - the compiler is trying to help.

Comment: `sizeof(msize) != 4096` and `sizeof(struct memory) != 4096` and `void read(struct memory *m)` //read arg pointer

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `scanf` an address to write to so need to change

```
scanf("%d", m.a[i]);
```

to

```
scanf("%d", &m.a[i]);
//          ^
```

You should also consider passing a pointer to `m` to `read` rather than passing this huge struct by value

```
void read(struct memory* m)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<msize;i++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &m->a[i]);
    }
}
```

(In fact your `read(&m)` call in `main` appears to already by assuming this update.)

Comment: I changed as above Then also its throwing an error within void read() as multiple definition of read and first defined here.

Comment: You need to either move `read` above `main` or provide a forward declaration above `main`.  See the answer from sje397 for details.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @simonc said, you should also declare the function up the top:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define msize 4096

struct memory
{
int a[msize];
};

void read(struct memory m);

void main()
{
//...
```

Comment: I made changes as you said then also its throwing an error as multiple definition of read and first defined here in void read function().

Comment: If you paste the exact text of the error that would help a lot. Try changing your function name - `read` is common.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define msize 4096
struct memory
{
int a[msize];
};

void read(struct memory *m)
{
int i;
for(i=0;i<sizeof(msize);i++)
 {
    scanf("%d",&m->a[i]);
 }
}

int main()
{
struct memory m;
m.a[0]=250; // temperature value of 25,0
m.a[4]=01; // heater status OFF
m.a[8]=240; // temperature value of 24,0
m.a[12]=00; // heater status ON
m.a[16]=220; // temperature value of 22,0
m.a[20]=00; // heater status ON
read(&m);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1. return type of main cant be void                                   2. read should have been placed before main                          3.as @simonic already said use scanf("%d", &m->a[i])         it will compile fine without any error

Comment: thank you very much!!! could you give me some ideas to convert this values to ASCII ??